# Automate google analytics into my data warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a solution to automate a few reports I have in Google Analytics.

I have seen there there are options to export csv data from GA and I can stage the data to import into a variant table, however I want to know what the best way to automate this might be.

So far I have found these two guides:

1. https://www.blendo.co/blog/load-data-from-google-analytics-to-snowflake/ - that explains that Blendo can help me automate this: https://www.blendo.co/integration/google-analytics-to-snowflake/
2. http://googleanalytics.tosnowflake.com/ - where it explains I can PUT the data and copy it into a table from an s3 stage and then automate with tools like Stich or a program of my own.

I have staged a few reports, is there a way I can connect the api and load everything automatically?

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168195/132438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you export Google Analytics data to your S3 bucket, you can use "Snowpipe" to load the data automatically:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html

The page explains how to automate Snowpipe with Amazon SQS and/or SNS, and Microsoft Azure Event Grid, and REST Endpoints.